# React state not updating. Use effect runs on attempt to change but has old state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am familiar with using useEffect’s ability to execute once a state variable has been updated.

I am creating this post about on my phone away from home.

My setup is this:

```
const [dateValue, setDateValue] = useState<Date | null>)(null);

useEffect(() => { 
    //useUpdateDateValueHere
} ,[dateValue]);
```

Date input On change method:

```
const newDate = new Date(e.target.value);
setDateValue(newDate)
```

Please keep in mind that this was written from Memory and any compilation errors did not exist on the original code.

Anyways, I debugged the date input on change and determined that it was the correct date I was changing it to. I let the setDateValue method execute and I had a breakpoint on the useEffect so it stopped there too. On the use effect I inspected the value and it was the old value and not the updated value.

I understand that react state does not update immediately after the setState methods. However in my experience when useEffect is used to listen for changes on a state variable the state veritable always has the updated value.

When I get home I will add the code that I used. It is apart Of a work project so I can’t share the entire repository.

I’ve never come across this bug and it throws what I know about useEffect our the window.

Comment: Waiting for the additional code :)

Comment: The code you've posted has no such problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-pond-ks4335?file=/src/App.tsx without a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) there is no question here.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys sorry for the delay. I looked at it last night and discovered it was additional code that I had above that was causing the problem:

```
const DateDataTypeWrapper: React.FC<DateDataTypeWrapperProps> = ({ styles, property, value, isIdentifierProperty }) => {
    const parsedDate = new Date(value);

    const [dateValue, setDateValue] = useState<Date | null>(null);
    const [dateString, setDateString] = useState<string>();

    if (parsedDate.toString() !== 'Invalid Date') {
        if (dateValue == undefined || dateValue.toString() != parsedDate.toString()) {
            setDateValue(parsedDate);
        }
    }
```

I don't quite understand how this code was overwriting the setDateValue I was doing before. Regardless, I moved this logic inside of the initializer of the state variable and now everything is working correctly.

Thanks to @Konrad Linkowski and @Alex Wayne for commenting on the question!

I apologize I underestimated the importance of having this code in the original question.